# Hide div but keep the empty space

Tags: jquery, css, html, hide

I have the following div element:

```css
.description {
  color: #b4afaf;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

```html
<div class="description">Some text here</div>
```

Then I have a click function on an element to hide the above div:

```
$('#target').click(function(){
  $(".description").hide();
});
```

When I hide the div, it collapses and stops taking up space. This messes up the layout of my page.

Is there a way to hide the div, but still maintain the space it was taking before? I don't want to change the font color because it would be still selectable.

Answer (score 199, accepted):

Use [visibility](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/visibility) css property for this

visibility:

> The visibility property specifies whether the boxes generated by an
>   element are rendered.

```
$(".description").css('visibility', 'hidden');
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/FGw8T/)

Answer (score 15):

And another option for the sake of completeness. Toggle `opacity`:

```
$(".description").css('opacity', 0); // hide
$(".description").css('opacity', 1); // show
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KPqwt/

However using `visibility` is prefered for this task.

Answer (score 13):

Try:

```
$(".description").css("visibility", "hidden")
```

`hide()` is the equivalent to: `$(".description").css("display", "none");`

Which does not reserve the space the element was taking.

`Hidden` makes the element invisible, but stills reserves the space.

Answer (score 8):

It's important to note that [dfsq](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16316543/4811012)'s example using Opacity:0 will still allow the contents to be selected, copy/pasted, etc., although there is no visible text-highlighting when selecting.

Answer (score 7):

There are many ways to do that in CSS.

- visibility: hidden;  // preferred
- transform: scale(0);
- z-index: -999999; // not work with specific positioning
- opacity: 0;  // click and input events still work

Answer (score 3):

you can wrap another div around the outside of it, and probably tell it a specific height to occupy. that way your inner div can show and hide and fadeOut, etc, and the outer div will hold down the real-estate on the page.

Comment: You could. But under what circumstances would you want to do this, when the accepted answer (from a year ago!) is simpler (no extra div needed), and does not require hard-coding a specific height? Even if you **wanted** a specific height, you wouldn't do this, you would just put the height in css on the already existing element. I don't mean to be rude, and I appreciate that it is good to have alternative solutions. I am just baffled by the suggestion of what appears to be an always-inferior solution, a year after the question was resolved? Am I missing something?